# Java : repaint is undefined in class

Tags: java, swing, paint, repaint, jcomponent

I am new on java. I want to create an abstract factory in java. I have a class `point` and I want to extend other classes ( `circle, rectangle` ) from this.

Here is my code. It says repaint is undefined..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Circle extends Point {

public void Draw() {
    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {       

    g.drawOval(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);

}...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `Point` simply encapsulates an `x` and `y` integer value. It is not derived from `java.awt.Component` so therefore `repaint` cannot be invoked.

For custom painting in Swing extend `JComponent` or `JPanel` and override `paintComponent` rather than `paint`. Remember to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`.

See: [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 2):

[repaint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) method is part of `java.awt.Component`.`Point` is not a subclass of `java.awt.Component`. You can't use it that way.